# Best and most Optimized way to Highlight Grid row using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gridview

I have a grid and I am using the jQuery code below to to highlight the row that the user selected.

But it's taking some time to select the row.
How can I optimize it?

```
function hightlightrow() {
  var index = "'Select$"+ $("#<%= highlightedRow.ClientID%>").val() +"'";
  $("#<%= UltraWebGrid1.ClientID%>").find("tr").each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('onclick')) {
      if ($(this).attr('onclick').indexOf(index) > 0) {
        $(this).addClass("highlight");
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass("highlight");
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Do you want to remove highlights from all other rows when a new row is clicked?

Comment: @pacifier21 yes

Comment: Try the second options in my answer - it tries to set up a click event callback for each of the table rows. Whenever any row is clicked, ALL rows lose the highlight class, and the clicked row adds the highlight class. Maybe it's faster?

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: @pacifier21 2nd one is not highlighting the ROW in the grid though it selecting the row

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "selecting the row" - is some attribute of the row changing? Is the clicked row not getting the "highlight" class? It's tough to provide a working example without some other details. Maybe the jquery selector is incorrect for the generated datagrid? Tough to say what is going wrong. Does the click callback even get invoked when a row is clicked? Is there something about a cell (td) click that is preventing the row click event (e.g., stopPropagation)?

Comment: row not highlighting that's all

Comment: Can you tell if the row tag (tr) is getting the "highlight" class assigned as it should? Do you have css styles defined for the highlighted row? In other words, just by adding the "highlight" class to a row does not mean that the row will change colors unless there is some css style rule that says it will. You will likely need a rule like "tr.highlight td { background-color: #229999; }"

Comment: yes css class is there

Comment: So, you see <tr class="highlight"> but it does not affect the row color. Is that correct? If yes, then you are missing appropriate style rules in your css files or in your page header. You need to define a css rule that will affect the color of your <td> tags within the <tr class="highlight">. Try the rule I provided in my previous comment to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to optimize slightly by storing the result of $(this) into a local variable. That way, it is not building a new jquery object each time.

```
function hightlightrow() {
    var index = "'Select$"+ $("#<%= highlightedRow.ClientID%>").val() +"'";
    $("#<%= UltraWebGrid1.ClientID%>").find("tr").each(function () {
        var $row = $(this);
        if ($row.attr('onclick')) {
            if ($row.attr('onclick').indexOf(index) > 0) {
                $row.addClass("highlight");
            } else {
                $row.removeClass("highlight");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Or, you could try something like this:

```
$("#<%= UltraWebGrid1.ClientID%> tr").click(function(event) {
    // Remove the highlight class from all rows up front
    $("#<%= UltraWebGrid1.ClientID%> tr").removeClass("highlight");

    $(event.target).addClass("highlight");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function hightlightrow() {
  $("#<%= UltraWebGrid1.ClientID%> tr").removeClass("highlight");
  $("#<%= UltraWebGrid1.ClientID%> tr[onclick*='" + $("#<%= highlightedRow.ClientID%>").val() + "']").first().addClass("highlight");
}
```

It will remove the `highlight` class everywhere, then will add it to the **first** `tr` which contain the `$("#<%= highlightedRow.ClientID%>")` value in its `onclick` attribute.

It should be faster than a loop.

Comment: your first selector does not select any rows - it selects the table

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette it is selecting all the rows when i am select the 1st row

Comment: This means the value you use to select the first row is also "contained" in the `onclick` of all other rows.

Comment: You could decide to select onle **the first** row that matches the criteria... I don't know if it can be correct in your page... But try it. (I edited my answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [GridView.SelectedRowStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedrowstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) property instead of javascript.
For example use declarative syntax:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="UltraWebGrid1">
   <!-- ... -->
   <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="highlight" />
   <!-- ... -->
</asp:GridView>
```

Or set the property programmatically while initialization:

```
UltraWebGrid1.SelectedRow.CssClass = "highlight";
```

Comment: Now THAT is likely the best answer!

Comment: I suggest you link the english version of the document in your answer... ;)

Comment: @Alexander how to use that ?

Comment: @DeepakJain, I'm sorry. I have fixed the link in my answer. You can see an example in the referenced MSDN article.

Comment: @Alexander sorry man but i want only the Jquery(need to refine my above code) thanks for ur effort

Comment: @DeepakJain, do you want to solve your quetion using client-side code only? By the way, I have added examples.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add class highlight whenever user click on Table Row and, remove same class when user again click on same table row then here's the code

```
 $("YourGridviewControl").on('click', 'tr', function () {
         $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
  });
```

Or If you want to remove Class From all rows and add only on one selected row, then your code looks like.

```
$("YourGridviewControl").on('click', 'tr', function () {
         $("YourGridviewControl tr").removeClass("highlight");
         $(this).addClass("highlight");
 });
```